# attribute error when using format - python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
D = {'z': {'A': 'Hello', 'B': 'World'}}
'{z.get("A")} {z.get("B")}'.format(**D)

*** AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'get("A")'
```

Why am I getting this error, and how should I fix it?

I'd like to print "Hello World"

Comment: what do you want to do in 2nd line?

Comment: I'd like to print `Hello World`

Comment: What is the output do you want ? Add it to your question.

Comment: @HirushaFernando added

Comment: @HappyPy Check my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use formatted strings in `python3`

```
D = {'z': {'A': 'Hello', 'B': 'World'}}
print(f"{D['z'].get('A')} {D['z'].get('B')}")
```

or you can try this

```
print(f"{D['z']['A']} {D['z']['B']}")
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't put arbitrary expressions inside the braces with `str.format`. f-strings support nearly-arbitrary expressions, but with `str.format`, you should move such computation outside the string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print the content of A and B try
`'{z[A]} {z[B]}'.format(**D)`